# vanilla-tilt only works after app has hot-updated once

Tags: javascript, svelte

I use `vanilla-tilt` in my svelte app.

When it loads the first time, it does seem to load tilt, as the item tilts ever so slightly. Although the max tilt I've defined doesn't load.

Then, if I change something arbitrary in my file so a hot update is triggered - voila, the tilt works as expected.

I've tried variations of calling the `Tilt.init` function, in the beginning of onMount, end of onMount, after a timeout of the page loads...

What to do?

Comment: A minimal, problem reproducing example would be helpful. Also the exact errors, if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

I use the tilt library in my Sveltekit project and defined it as a simple action.

With [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/actions) actions, you always know the node will be available, the moment you initialize your code. This is the main reason I recommend this approach.

**effects.js**

```
import VanillaTilt from 'vanilla-tilt'

export function tilt (node, options) {
  VanillaTilt.init(node, options)

  return {
        destroy() {
            VanillaTilt.destroy()
        }
    };
}
```

In your component, just use the action as you're used to

**component.svelte**

```
<script>
  import { tilt } from "./effects.js"
</script>

<div use:tilt>
  <!-- your tilting content -->
</div>
```